# Is the limit of $f/f'$ necessarily $0$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Let $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ be differentiable on $[a,b]$, with $\lim\limits_{x\to a}f(x)=\lim\limits_{x\to a}f^\prime(x)=0$, and $f^\prime(x)\ne 0$ in a neighborhood of $a$. Is it necessarily true that

$$\lim_{x\to a}\frac{f(x)}{f^\prime(x)}=0$$

It doesn't seem necessarily clear to me that this limit should always exist, and that there's not some pathological function for which the limit is nonzero.

Answer (score 4):

We can prove that $f'/f$ must be unbounded in any neighborhood of $a$.

First, we impose a fairly weak condition that $f'$ is integrable. By hypothesis $f' \neq 0$ in some interval $(a,b]$. Since derivatives have the intermediate value property (Darboux's theorem) we must have either $f'(x) > 0$ or $f'(x) < 0$ for all $x \in (a,b]$.

Since $f(x) \to 0$ as $x \to a+$, it follows that $f$ is increasing if $f' > 0$ with $f(x) > 0$ and $f'(x)/f(x) > 0$ for $x \in (a,b]$. On the other hand, if $f' < 0$ then $f$ is decreasing with  $f(x) < 0$ and $f'(x)/f(x)  > 0$ for $x \in (a,b].$

Since $f'/f$ is integrable we have

$$\int_{a+\delta}^b \frac{f'(x)}{f(x)} \,dx = \int_{f(a+\delta)}^{f(b)} \frac{dy}{y} = \log f(b) - \log f(a + \delta).$$

Thus, since $\log f(a + \delta) \to -\infty$ as $\delta \to 0+$ we have

$$\int_a^b \frac{f'(x)}{f(x)} \, dx = \lim_{\delta \to 0+} \int_{a+\delta}^b \frac{f'(x)}{f(x)} \,dx = +\infty,$$

and, thus,

$$\limsup_{x \to a+} \frac{f'(x)}{f(x)} = + \infty, \quad \liminf_{x \to a+} \frac{f(x)}{f'(x)} = 0$$

**Another approach that does not require $f'$ to be integrable**

For any points $y > x >a$ there exists $\xi_{x,y}$ between $x$ and $y$ such that

$$\log f(y) - \log f(x) = \frac{f'(\xi_{x,y})}{f(\xi_{x,y})}(y-x).$$

Thus,

$$\lim_{x \to a+} \frac{f'(\xi_{x,y})}{f(\xi_{x,y})} = [\log f(y) - \lim_{x \to a+} \log f(x)]/(y- a) = + \infty.$$

Hence, on any interval $(a,y]$ no matter how small we can find a sequence of points $(x_n)$ such that $f'(x_n)/f(x_n) \to + \infty.$ The mean value theorem is non-constructive, so we cannot determine that $x_n \to a$ or more generally that $\lim_{x \to a+} \xi_{x,y}= a.$  This shows, at least, that $f'/f$ must be unbounded in any neighborhood of $x=a$, and again

$$\liminf_{x \to a+} \frac{f(x)}{f'(x)} = 0$$

Also, the hypothesis that $f'(x) \to 0$ as $x \to a+$ was never used.

Comment: Very cool! I only required $f'(x)\to 0$ because if $f'(x)\to c$ for $c\ne 0$ then it is easily shown $f/f'\to 0$, and if the limit of $f'$ does not exist then I have found examples where the limit of $f/f'$ does not exist. I have one remaining question: how do we deduce that $f'/f$ is integrable given that $f'$ is integrable?

Comment: @strombc: Thanks.  The argument uses that $f'/f$ is integrable on any interval $[a+\delta,b]$ where $\delta > 0$ and then goes on to show that the improper integral diverges. Since $f$ is continuous it is integrable and so too is $f'/f$.  We don't need to worry that $f(x) = 0$ anywhere in the interval since it approaches $0$ montonically from above or below as $x \to a+$.

Comment: I think the proof falls apart where you conclude that the limit must be infinite just because the integral diverges. Basically, consider the function $g$ which linearly interpolates between the two values $n^2$ and $1$ on the interval $[\frac1{n+1},\frac1{n}]$. Here the improper integral diverges, but it is certainly not true that $\lim_{x\to 0}g(x) = +\infty$!

Comment: @Shalop: I think you are correct. At least we must have $f'/f$ unbounded with $\limsup f'/f = +\infty$ and $\liminf f/f' = 0$.

Answer (score 2):

Other answers have been approaching a construction of a counterexample, and I'm convinced with some more work one should be possible.  What you *can* say, however, is that
$$\liminf_{x\to a^+} \frac{f(x)}{f'(x)} = 0.$$
First, notice that by Rolle's theorem, $f$ can't have zeros on any interval $(a, a + \delta)$ where $f'$ has no zeros; so $\frac{f}{f'}$ cannot change signs, and from here, it is straightforward to conclude that $\frac{f(x)}{f'(x)} > 0$ for $x \in (a, a + \delta)$.

Now, suppose that $\liminf_{x\to a^+} \frac{f(x)}{f'(x)} = \epsilon > 0$.  Then for some $\delta' > 0$, we have $\frac{f(x)}{f'(x)} > \frac{\epsilon}{2}$ for $x \in (a, a + \delta')$.  It follows that $$\frac{d}{dx}(\log |f(x)|) = \frac{f'(x)}{f(x)} < \frac{2}{\epsilon}$$ for $x \in (a, a + \delta')$.  Therefore, $$\log |f(x)| > \log |f(a + \delta')| - \frac{2}{\epsilon} (a + \delta' - x)$$ for each $x \in (a, a + \delta')$.  This contradicts the assumption that $f(a) = 0$ and $f$ is differentiable and therefore continuous, so $\log |f(x)| \to -\infty$ as $x \to a^+$.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is  not necessarily true that the limit is $0$.

Indeed consider a function $f:[0, 1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(0)=0$, $f'(0)=0$ and for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, 
$$f\left( \frac{1}{n} \right) = \frac{1}{n} \quad \text{and} \quad f'\left( \frac{1}{n} \right) = \frac{1}{n^2}$$

I think this is not difficult to show that such a function exists. But such a function would not satisfy your limit property.

Comment: I am not sure this function would satisfy the hypothesis that the limit of the derivative goes to 0. I believe that such a function would need arbitrarily steep slopes to be continuous.

Comment: Hmmm you are right... But I still think that a counterexample is possible. I may be wrong, but I have to think a little bit more !

Comment: I don't know about unbounded derivative - but certainly, by the mean value theorem for each $n$ there is $c \in (\frac{1}{n+1}, \frac{1}{n})$ such that $f'(c)=1$ making it impossible for $f'$ to have limit 0.  On the other hand, I think if you start with a base of $f(x) = x^2$, then perturb it on small intervals so that $f(1/n) = 1/n^2$ and $f'(1/n) = 1/n^3$ then that should work to produce a counterexample.

Answer (score 1):

I think it indeed should always be $0$. Look at the following line of reasoning (where $f(a):=0$):
$$ \lim_{x\to a} \frac{f(x)}{f'(x)} = \lim_{x\to a} \left(\frac{f(x) - f(a)}{x-a}\right)/{f'(x)}\cdot (x-a) = \lim_{x\to a} 1\cdot(x-a) = 0.  $$
It only needs to be verified that
$$ \lim_{x\to a}\left(\frac{f(x) - f(a)}{x-a}\right)/{f'(x)} = 1.$$
I am pretty sure the latter holds but I am unsure about the proof.

**EDIT:** Without loss of generality, assume that $x>a$. Using the mean value theorem, we derive that for all $x$ there exists a $a<c_x<x$ such that $(f(x)-f(a))/(x-a) = f'(c_x)$. It follows that
$$ \lim_{x\to a}\left(\frac{f(x) - f(a)}{x-a}\right)/{f'(x)} = \lim_{x\to a} f'(c_x)/f'(x) = 1 $$ 
where the last step is valid if $f'(x)$ is continuous at $a$, since $f'(x)\to 0$ as $x\to a$, this must hold true. Because if it is not continuous, this limit cannot exist.

**Edit2** the last claim is not true as seen in the questions. If you want to find a counterexample, it is a good way to start by looking at functions for which the above statement does not hold.

Comment: I thought so too but it hasn't convinced me yet

Comment: @eyeballfrog No, because this is a limit of the form $0/0$.

Comment: @egreg Oh right, duh.

Comment: Note that it is actually allowed to be infinite for the proof to still hold as long as it doesn't 'grow' quicker than of the order $1/(x-a)$.

Comment: I think I have the idea for the last step, as an application to the mean value theorem

Comment: Well $f'$ is indeed continuous at $a$ with $f'(a) =0$ but that does not help us in figuring out the limit.

Comment: Consider $f(x)=x^2$ on $[0,1]$. Then for the final limit you want to show, the mean value theorem guarantees the existence of $c_x\in[0,x]$ such that $f'(c_x)=f(x)/x\implies 2c_x=x^2/x$, so we must have $c_x=x/2$. Then computing the limit of $f'(c_x)/f'(x)$, we have that this is the limit of $2(x/2)/2x$, which equals $1/2$, not $1$. In fact, we can see this if we just evaluate the original limit, as it reduces to $(\frac{x^2-0}{x-0})/2x=1/2$ (the problem is that the $c_x$'s approach 0 twice as fast as $x$). I do appreciate the ideas though, I have found this question surprisingly slippery!

Comment: Yeah you are right, although as long as it does not blow up the final result still holds.

Answer (score 1):

The claim is not true.

Let $f'(x) = \frac1{n^2}$ for $x \in [\frac1{2n+1},\frac1{2n}]$, and let $f'(x) = \frac1{2n}$ for $x \in (\frac1{2n},\frac1{2n-1})$. Here $n \ge 1$.

Let $f(x) = \int_0^x f'(u)du$. One verifies that $$f\big(\frac1{2n}\big) \geq \sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty} \int_{\frac1{2k}}^{\frac1{2k-1}}f'(u)du = \sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty}\bigg[ \frac1{2k-1}-\frac1{2k}\bigg] \frac{1}{2k} \geq \sum_{k=n}^{\infty} \frac1{8k^3}\geq \frac{1}{16n^2}.$$ Consequently, $$\frac{f(\frac1{2n})}{f'(\frac1{2n})} \geq \frac1{16}.$$

Comment: The values don't match up at $\frac{1}{2n}$ so the integral isn't in fact differentiable at $\frac{1}{2n}$ whereas the question requires differentiability at every point in a neighborhood of $a$.  It should hopefully be straightforward to fix this by doing linear patches between the even/odd terms on small intervals around $\frac{1}{n}$.

Comment: @DanielSchepler You are definitely right. In practice, it is not a real problem since we can linearly interpolate on much smaller intervals around $1/n$ (say of size $2^{-n}$), and this will not change any of the intricate details but only slightly complicate them (e.g., one should then consider $f'(\frac{1}{2n+1/2})/f(\frac{1}{2n+1/2})$).

Comment: Or, just do the patches slightly to one side of $\frac{1}{n}$.